# how does C compiles "senthil""kumar" in a printf statement?

Tags: c, string, printf

I've doubt regarding the basics of C language while using printf statement.
well this is how my code looks like.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("%s %s",("senthil""kumar"),("hello""world"),("stack""overflow");
return 0;}
```

I've got an output like,
senthilkumar helloworld

but i don't how does this code works.
could u pls help me to figure out how it works...
thanx in advance.

Comment: You are forcing `printf` to work overtime without incentives.

Comment: The code won't compile due to unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: don't ask that read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#String_literal_concatenation) it should be good enough for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two consecutive string literals are merged by the compiler.

I.e. the following examples are equivalent:

```
// 1:
"foo" "bar"
// 2:
"foobar"
// 3:
#define FOO "foo"
FOO "bar"
```

You do not need all those inner parentheses (also, there's a `)` missing at the end).

Comment: Yeah. But there are only two specifiers for three string literals in the question.